# GWT DialogBox Has Gaps In Border For Larger Messages

Tags: css, gwt

Working with GWT v2.5.1, I'm creating a DialogBox and filling it using HTML by calling `dialog.setHTML(...)` with this:

```
<h3>could not start.</h3>
<hr>
<p>These preferences must all be set before I can start</p>
```

I have no custom CSS.  What appears on the screen is this:

[image: DialogBox with gaps in side borders]

You'll notice that there are big gaps in the left and right borders.  Looking at the CSS for the `dialogTopLeft` and `dialogTopRight` classes, they extract the border from images/corner.png and the shown length of the border exactly matches the size of that image.  In other words, the dialog is too big.

I tried removing the "no-repeat" directive on the `background` CSS attribute (using Chrome Inspector) but that repeats the entire border image, including the rounded corner at the top, and so does not appear contiguous.

I can't be the first person who's tried to put more than a single line into a DialogBox...

*What's the trick to making the borders "repeat" and fill in the holes?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Moh for placing me on the right path.

The proper way to do this is to set only the dialog title using `setHTML()` and then create the body as a new panel and add it to the dialog.

```
DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();
dialog.setHTML("<b>" + title + "</b>");
dialog.add(new HTMLPanel(message));
```

Adding buttons is left as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the HTML in HTMLPanel befor passing it to the DialogBox

```
DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();
HTMLPanel panel  = new HTMLPanel("<h3>could not start.</h3><hr><p>These preferences must all be set before I can start</p>");
dialog.add(panel);
dialog.center();
```

Answer (score -1):

GWT Dialoge box already have pre defined CSS.
you have to override or have to set your own style names using set Methods.
like..

```
dialogBox.setStyleName("yourcss");
```

Default css names starts with,

```
.gwt-DialogBox{}
```

Comment: I know it can be styled.  I want to know why it's not working out-of-the-box.